# How to exclude jar that contains StaticLoggerBinder from activemq-all maven dependency?

Tags: java, maven, logging, apache-camel, slf4j

I'm using ActiveMQ (an apache camel component) to send SMS from web to GSM mobile, so I needed to use SLF4J. 
I got this in the output of my netbeans project when i run it
it seems like the jar is present two times, and i think that i need to add an exclusion in the dependency in my pom.xml but i dont know what to do exactly !

This is the part of SLF4 in my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<!-- logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.5</version>

    <!--  <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions> -->
</dependency>
```

And this is my output while running my project

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/asus/.m2/repository/org/apache/activemq/activemq-all/5.9.0/activemq-all-5.9.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/asus/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.5/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
    <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
    <version>5.9.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

See more in [*[AMQ-5009] Switch activemq-all from shaded jar to pom dependency aggregator - ASF JIRA*](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5009).

Answer (score 3):

Your question is lacking a bit of context, but I'd say you should simply drop that `slf4j-log4j12` dependency from your POM, since an SLF4J binding is embedded in `activemq-all-5.9.0.jar` anyway.

Or maybe you could try not using `activemq-all` with embedded dependencies and use individual ActiveMQ artifacts with ordinary transitive dependencies.

Comment: I agree with not using activemq-all, instead using the individual dependencies you need.  In general I've found that using '-all' dependencies can create problems.  Typically these repackage other dependencies where the normal Maven dependency resolution process can't get at them.  Then, if you need to use a later version of an embedded dependency, problems result, and it's tricky/time-consuming to track down.

Comment: That depends on whether amq us intentionally claiming control of the entire SLF4J infrastructure, or mistakenly incorporating an slf4j backend.

Comment: @user944849 please make that an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with not using activemq-all, instead using the individual dependencies you need. In general I've found that using '-all' dependencies can create problems. Typically these repackage other dependencies where the normal Maven dependency resolution process can't get at them. Then, if you need to use a later version of an embedded dependency, problems result, and it's tricky/time-consuming to track down.

(Making this comment an answer per @bmargulies request.)